# Ellipse bounding rectangle

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections, rectangles

I'm trying to find the ellipse that bounds a rectangle in a way that the "distance" between the rectangle and the ellipse is the same vertically and horizontally.

Here is an image to illustrate what I mean:

[image: illustration]

It's not perfectly drawn but the two "x" dimension need to be the same.

What I tried so far is:

The ellipse equation is $$\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2 = 1$$

- The "ellipse bounding the rectangle" constraint gives us $$\left(\frac{w}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{h}{b}\right)^2 = 1$$
- The "x dimension must be equal" constraint gives us $a-w = b-h$

So it's basically a $2$ equations system with $2$ unknowns.

But I got stuck at this point. If I do a substitution I have

- $$a = b-h+w$$
- $$\left(\frac{w}{b-h+w}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2 = 1$$

and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: What do not you center everything (ellipse + rectangle) at (0,0) ?

Comment: I think I did, didn't I? The illustration might be false though (in a way "a", "b", "w" and "h" might actually be "2a", "2b", "2w" and  "2h"). But it doesn't change the problem much.

Comment: Are you looking for the smallest allipse or for any ellipse containing the rectangle ? Michael Albanese and I did not understand the same thing. Please clarify.

Comment: I looking for the ellipse that goes through the rectangle edges.

Comment: Have you be able to continue with what I gave you as an answer ?

Comment: I believe this is the desired answer to the question posed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433371/ellipse-bounding-a-rectangle#answer-6716520

Comment: By the way, what you are asking for, that distance x is the same on the width as the height, is impossible.  What I think you really want is the same aspect ratio for the ellipse as the rectangle.  This is what the answer I posted in the previous comment does

Answer (score 1):

If you centre the rectangle on the origin, then it has vertices at $(-\frac{w}{2}, -\frac{h}{2})$, $(\frac{w}{2}, -\frac{h}{2})$, $(\frac{w}{2}, \frac{h}{2}),$ and $(-\frac{w}{2}, \frac{h}{2})$.

An ellipse centred at the origin has equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ where $a$ is the 'horizontal' radius, and $b$ is the 'vertical' radius (here I am taking $a$, $b$ positive). Then the ellipse you are looking for must satisfy

$$a-\frac{w}{2} = b - \frac{h}{2}$$

or equivalently

$$2a - w = 2b - h.$$

If $w$ and $h$ are given, this is one equation between the two unknowns $a$ and $b$. This corresponds to the fact that there is an infinite family of ellipses which satisfies the distance condition.

You need one more piece of information to uniquely determine the ellipse. For example, if you would like the ellipse to go through the vertices of the rectangle, then we must have

$$\frac{\left(\dfrac{w}{2}\right)^2}{a^2} + \frac{\left(\dfrac{h}{2}\right)^2}{b^2} = \frac{w^2}{(2a)^2} + \frac{h^2}{(2b)^2} = 1.$$

Rearranging $b$ for $a$ in the previous equation, we obtain $b = a + \frac{1}{2}(h-w)$. Substituting into the latter equation, we see that $a$ must satisfy

$$\frac{w^2}{(2a)^2} + \frac{h^2}{(2a + h - w)^2} = 1$$

which, when rearranged, is a quartic in $a$.

Note, if $h = w$ (i.e. the rectangle is a square), then $a = b = \frac{w}{2}\sqrt{2}$ so the ellipse is a circle with radius equal to the distance between the origin and a vertex of the square (as one would expect).

**Example:** If $h = 1$ and $w = 2$ we obtain

$$\frac{4}{(2a)^2} + \frac{1}{(2a-1)^2} = 1$$

which becomes

$$4a^4-4a^3-4a^2+4a-1=0.$$

This only has two real roots, but the only positive one is $a = 1.2908$. From the first equation, we then see that $b = 0.7908$.

The result can be seen below (made using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x/1.2908%29%5E2%2b%28y/0.7908%29%5E2%20=%201,%20y=0.5,%20y=-0.5,%20x=%20-1,%20x=1)).

[image]

Comment: I thought that the OP was looking for the largest recatngle or the smallest ellipse. If this is not the case, you are right and .... I am wrong. Happy New Year !!

Comment: So yeah... it's a quartic as I suspected :( Which means the solution is a monster :D I'm going to take a look to the heuristic since I going to use that in an IT project.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: My interpretation was that the rectangle is given, and the ellipse is sought after. Hopefully the OP will be able to provide some clarification.

Comment: @user1534422: Unless you want a general formula, using a calculator to solve the resulting quartic should be sufficient.

Comment: If my approach is correct, there is no quartic but only quadratic.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Are you sure? Are you taking the rectangle as fixed or the ellipse?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese. I fixed the ellipse and made the recatngle as large as possible. But since we still do not know the OP's answer ...

Comment: The rectangle is fixed and the ellipse is "outside" the rectangle. I'm wondering, can you guys see the image in the question? I thought the illustration was explaining the problem pretty well but I might be wrong ;)

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese yes I need the general formula since I will use that in a programming project. So I need to be able to compute the ellipse width and height dynamically. But I don't need a lot of precision (actually I just need the integer part, I don't even need one decimal). So a simple dichotomy to solve the quartic should be enough.

Comment: @user1534422: The image does appear, but it does not indicate which shape is given and which is to be determined. As for your programming project, presumably you feed the width and height before you run your program. If this is the case, can't you then solve the quartic numerically to sufficiently high accuracy?

Comment: Nope, I can't compute them before :( It needs to be done during runtime so I need the generic solution. But like I said even if I have something giving me the exact solution I will round the result. So I don't need to compute the exact solution.

Comment: Surely you can compute solutions within your program. That is, get the input, solve the quartic to relevant accuracy, use solution in the next part of the program.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese. Starting with the ellipse and computing the largest rectangle satisfying the condition leads to a very simple quadratic equation in "a" (refer to my notations). The corresponding value of "x" is given by (a^3 - a^2 b + Sqrt[2] a^(3/2) b^(3/2))/(a^2 + b^2) and the corresponding "y" is given by b Sqrt[1 - (x/a)^2]. Setting a=1.2908 and b=0.7908 as in your answer leads to x=1.00002 and y=0.500019 which properly matches your case.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let us put everything centered at (0,0) and since everything is symmetrical, we shall just look at the first quadrant.

So you look for a value of "x", smaller than "a", such that (a - x) be equal to (b - y). But you know that the upright corner of the rectangle is also along the ellipse. This means that

y = b Sqrt[1 - (x/a)^2].

Can you continue from here ?

**Happy New Year**

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I found myself doing a bunch of math to reduce it down to my use case. In case it helps anyone else, here's the (Python 3) class method I ended up with:

```
    def _describeEllipse(self, widthIn, heightIn):
        """
        Adapted from
        https://math.stackexchange.com/a/623933
        """
        w, h = widthIn, heightIn
        k = 2 * h * w**3 - h**2 * w**2 - w**4
        coeffs = [16, 16 * (h - w), -8 * h * w, 4 * w**2 * (w - h), k]
        solutions = np.roots(coeffs)
        validSolutions = np.array([np.real(x) for x in solutions if np.isreal(x) and x > 0])
        assert len(validSolutions) > 0, "No physical solutions found for ellipse"
        bPool = validSolutions + .5 * (h - w)
        goodPairs = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(validSolutions, bPool) if y > 0]
        assert len(goodPairs) > 0, "No semimajor/semiminor physical combination found"
        # There really should only be one valid solution, but in case there isn't, 
        # return the first
        return goodPairs[0]
```